# Check each paragraph contains any bold element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to scan through all the `p`, and then check if the `p` does not contain any `b`. But when my script below does not working properly.

When I set the condition as below, all `p` is not highlighted.

```
!$.contains($(this), 'b')
```

I tried as below, but it will highlight all `p`.

```
!$.contains($(this), 'b')
```

Is this `$(this)` returned all `p` instead of the particular `p` during the loop?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    if (!$.contains($(this), 'b')) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p><b>I live in Duckburg.</b>
</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
  <li>Goofy</li>
  <li>Mickey</li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in association with `:not()` selector

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
$('p:not(:has(b))').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

OR

```
$('p').not(':has(b)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p:not(:has(b))').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p><b>I live in Duckburg.</b>
</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
  <li>Goofy</li>
  <li>Mickey</li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `:not()` selector if not mistaken it does not support in IE8. I need to have a script that can support until IE8.

Comment: @chin Is is not supported, Please test it once, Alternnaviley you can use `$('p').not(':has(b)').css('background-color', 'yellow');` i.e. `.not()` method

Comment: It seems like both working with my IE8. But I remember previously I hit error when using `not` selector, `:not` and `.not()`.

Comment: @Chin, I haven't face any issue as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** for selecting element which contains `b` then use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** to avoid them

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').not(':has(b)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p><b>I live in Duckburg.</b>
</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
  <li>Goofy</li>
  <li>Mickey</li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or you can use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').filter(function() {
    return $('b', this).length == 0;
  }).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p><b>I live in Duckburg.</b>
</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
  <li>Goofy</li>
  <li>Mickey</li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does `:has()` selector supported in IE8?

Comment: Tested both, seems like both working on IE8. But I think I'll go for the `filter()`, as I remember last time I hit error with `:not` and `.not()` selector.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('b').length > 0) {
        alert($(this).find('b').text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$('p').find('b').each(function(){
$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')})
```